# How to create a secure view with Vaadin and SpringViewProvider

Tags: java, spring, vaadin

There is a tutorial about Vaadin [III - Views and Navigation with Vaadin Spring](https://vaadin.com/wiki?p_p_id=36&p_p_lifecycle=0&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&p_p_col_id=row-1&p_p_col_pos=1&p_p_col_count=3&_36_struts_action=%2Fwiki%2Fview&p_r_p_185834411_nodeName=vaadin.com%20wiki&p_r_p_185834411_title=III%20-%20Views%20and%20Navigation%20with%20Vaadin%20Spring)

If I want to use Apache Shiro. How should I use ViewAccessControl?

```
@SpringComponent
@SpringView(name = SecuredView.VIEW_NAME)
public class SecuredView extends VerticalLayout implements View, ViewAccessControl {

    public static final String VIEW_NAME = "view";

    @PostConstruct
    void init() {
        addComponent(new Label("This is a secured view scoped view"));
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isAccessGranted(UI ui, String string) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

I get the exception:

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securedView': Scope 'vaadin-view' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No active view

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're trying to inject the bean in a narrow context.
e.g.  SpringUI : UIScope => SpringView : ViewScope
Try to have a look "inside" annotation, they carry already the SpringComponent
Cheers