# Using ViewAccessControl in Spring and Vaadin

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot, vaadin, vaadin4spring

I am currently trying to use the ViewAccessControl Interface of vaadin.spring as explained in the last paragraph of [this](https://vaadin.com/wiki?p_p_id=36&p_p_lifecycle=0&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&_36_struts_action=%2Fwiki%2Fview&_36_pageResourcePrimKey=9365400&p_r_p_185834411_nodeName=vaadin.com+wiki&p_r_p_185834411_title=III+-+Views+and+Navigation+with+Vaadin+Spring) tutorial.

But when implementing the isAccessGranted Method I get the following error:

`org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'frontPageView': Scope 'vaadin-view' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No active view`

The declaration of the FrontPageView class (The only thing I do in the enter method, is to add some vaadin ui elements):

```
@SpringView(name = FrontPageView.NAME)
public class FrontPageView extends DashboardDesign implements View, ViewAccessControl {

    @Override
    public void enter(ViewChangeEvent event) {

    }

}
```

And my implementation of the isAccessGranted Method:

```
@Override
public boolean isAccessGranted(UI ui, String beanName) {
        return SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().isAuthenticated();
}
```

P.S. Its basically the same problem this guy had a year ago: [How to create a secure view with Vaadin and SpringViewProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29481899/how-to-create-a-secure-view-with-vaadin-and-springviewprovider)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I figured it out now. If anyone else ever finds this problem, the solution is to use the ViewInstanceAccessControl interface instead of the ViewAccessControl iterface. Everything works fine this way.